# Curses in Python2.7.10 / 3.4.3 addstr() error

Tags: python, curses

I am testing out the curses module for python and I encountered this error while trying a simple script:

> NameError: global name 'addstr' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses, sys
from curses import *

def main():

    stdscr = initscr()

    addstr("Hello")

    endwin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't know what Newbie mistake I made, I am following a guide for curses on python.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addstr()` on `stdscr`, since that is the window object. Here's an example of a curses application:

```py
import curses
import time

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()

stdscr.addstr("Hello World")
stdscr.refresh()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.001)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

curses.nocbreak()
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

Note that the `while` loop is simply so the curses terminal is displayed until you hit Ctrl-C, otherwise you won't really see much.

Comment: Wow I'm a real dummy! I guess I wasn't paying attention... THANKS!